# How to select an entry from the rows of numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to select number like `36/5` from string, but does not get the result.
I can only select number 36.

Code:

```
DECLARE @s nvarchar(255);
SET @s = 'http://kbyte.ru/ru/Programming/Sources.aspx?id=36/5&mode=show'
-- берем переднюю  часть строки, начиная с числа
SELECT @s = SUBSTRING(@s, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @s), LEN(@s));
-- отсекаем хвост до числа
SELECT @s = SUBSTRING(@s, 0, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @s));
-- выводим
SELECT @s;
```

Answer (score 2):

If your string is always going to be in that format just add **/** to your second pattern index.

```
DECLARE @s nvarchar(255);
SET @s = 'http://kbyte.ru/ru/Programming/Sources.aspx?id=36/5&mode=show'
SELECT @s = SUBSTRING(@s, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @s), LEN(@s));
SELECT @s = SUBSTRING(@s, 0, PATINDEX('%[^0-9/]%', @s));
SELECT @s;
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative if you're always going to retrieve 4 characters. Otherwise you can tweak it to how you need.

```
 DECLARE @s nvarchar(255);
 SET @s = 'http://kbyte.ru/ru/Programming/Sources.aspx?id=36/5&mode=show'
 SELECT @s= SUBSTRING(@s,(CHARINDEX('id=',@s)+3),4)
 SELECT @s;
```

**EDIT**

This may solve the problem of limited characters... This will work if your value is always between "id=" and "&mode"

```
 DECLARE @s nvarchar(255);
 DECLARE @int INT
 SET @s = 'http://kbyte.ru/ru/Programming/Sources.aspx?id=36/5&mode=show'
 SELECT @int = CHARINDEX('&mode',@s) - (CHARINDEX('id=',@s)+3)
 SELECT @s= SUBSTRING(@s,(CHARINDEX('id=',@s)+3),@int)
 SELECT @s;
```

Comment: In case if the numeric count is increase, your code will not support.

Comment: "... if you're always going to retrieve 4 characters."